# Hosting multiple WordPress installations

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, permissions, hosting

I'm going to host multiple WordPress-installations on my dedicated LAMP-server (Ubuntu). All installations will be under folder /var/www/wordpress/.

For example, if I have two customers:

CUSTOMER NAME - WORDPRESS PATH

customer1 - /var/www/wordpress/customer1/

customer2 - /var/www/wordpress/customer2/

Customers will get only access to WordPress control panel but I'm wondering of security because there is for example possibility to run PHP-scripts.

How can I limit customer1 access to only folder /var/www/wordpress/customer1 and disable internal scripts and other security problems? Should I allow only some file extensions via .htaccess? How should I change each folder's permissions?

Thank you very much for answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [chroot jails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)

The chroot system call changes the root directory of the current and all child processes to the given path, and this is nearly always some restricted subdirectory below the real root of the filesystem. This new path is seen entirely as "/" by the process, and we refer to this restricted environment as the "jail". It's not possible to escape this jail except in very limited circumstances.

This could allow you to jail your users to a particular directory while still being able to serve their home folder with apache using virtual hosts.

This practice is often used in shared hosting.

Comment: Again, not an answer, just a link. Maybe you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Also I am interested, how would you use chroot jails while using a single instance of Apache?

Comment: If interested then ask a question.
And please stop bugging me, I'm here to help, so please don't waste my time with your bad mood.

Comment: I dont need to, this guy did, but there are no answer yet. I did not realise, or care, who put this comment up as an answer. So I am not targeting you, just trying to be a good Stack citizen.

Comment: Still this user gets an answer, post a better one and I'll gladly remove mine. :-)